# Is it possible to embed a PDF on a Cloudflare Workers' subdomain?

Tags: html, pdf, cloudflare

Been successful in embedding youtube videos, webpages and images into a Cloudflare Workers' subdomain.  I have tried a few codes to embed a PDF.  All I get is white space where the pdf should be.  Has anyone been successful in getting a pdf to show up in a Workers' site?  If so, can you help?  Thank you.

Comment: Post your code of what you have tried so far

Comment: I have tried iframe, object and embed codes.  None of them show the embed.  All I get is white screen where the embed should be.